# android minimum api level of camera

Tags: android, camera

So I am on my first application project and it has a feature that it can take a picture from the app,my client wants to know tha minimum api level for this feature and i am not sure about it,i searched about it but got no clear idea about it.So I want to know what is the minimum api level of opening a camera from another application?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) it says API level 3 using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent. Other similar intents were added after that, but that is the most basic one you would need to open the native (or other) camera apps installed on the device.

Comment: Thanks Gerard for the help!